# Header on my website does not extend to the left and right as I wish

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a navigation bar that stretches from the logo to the right side of the window. I would like to avoid the use of percentages for responsiveness. In the image below the circle represents the logo.

I have this:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

The problem is, I can't get the background like in picture 2 but responsive with the container.

I have this code:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1100px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.site-nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
  background: #fee17c;
}

.site-nav .nav-logo {
  height: 230px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
}

.site-nav .nav-logo img {
  height: 160px;
  margin: auto;
  background:red;
}

.site-nav .nav-links {
  height: 230px;
  float: right;
}

.site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box {
  height: 230px;
  display: flex;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: red;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    padding: 1rem 0 1rem 0;
  }
  .site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding: .7rem 1rem .7rem 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: right;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 1rem;
  }
  .site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box ul li:not(:last-child) {
    padding-right: 1rem;
  }
  .site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box ul li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: .5s;
  }
  .site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box ul li a:hover {
    color: #0864bb;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 230px;
    left: 0;
    background: 768px-bg;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fee17c;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  }
  .site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box ul li {
    padding: 1rem 0 1rem 1.5rem;
  }
  .site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box ul.show {
    display: block;
  }
}

.site-nav .nav-links .toggle-nav {
  width: 35px;
  height: 230px;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .site-nav .nav-links .toggle-nav {
    display: block;
  }
}

.site-nav .nav-links .toggle-nav .dashes {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.site-nav .nav-links .toggle-nav .dashes .dash {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #0864bb;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: transform .4s, -webkit-transform .4s;
}

.site-nav .nav-links .toggle-nav .dashes .dash:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.site-nav .nav-links .toggle-nav.show .dashes .dash:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(9px) rotate(45deg);
}

.site-nav .nav-links .toggle-nav.show .dashes .dash:nth-child(2) {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.site-nav .nav-links .toggle-nav.show .dashes .dash:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<nav class="site-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-logo">
      <img src="assets/frontend/img/logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- .nav-logo -->
    <div class="nav-links">
      <button class="toggle-nav">
          <span class="dashes" aria-hidden="true">
              <span class="dash"></span>
              <span class="dash"></span>
              <span class="dash"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="txt">Menu</span>
      </button>
      <!-- .toggle-nav -->
      <div class="nav-links-box">
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .nav-links -->
  </div>
  <!-- .container -->
</nav>
<!-- .site-nav -->
```

Anyone help me please?

Comment: Your posted code sample doesn't render as your non-working image show. Please edit and update it so it does.

Comment: @lGSon How do I make it work when I need the pictures? Is that the same when I have it responsive?

Comment: @user7355869 waves is missing..

Comment: `@sanojlawrence @lgson Now I added the background, I don't know how to add picture into code. I think now that's approaching the picture and the only problem is in the background so it can be like it is now.

Comment: Right away, you're setting `display: flex` on the wrong elements. You only want to use `display: flex` on parent divs which have flex children. Victoria's answer below is the correct method of doing what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the background of the menu to reach the logo, you need to have the `.container` have `display: flex`, not the logo. Then you can remove the `float` properties and make the menu have `flex-grow: 1;`

Here's an example that works for desktop. I commented out all the media so that it's a little easier to see on StackOverflow, but you'll have to add them back and adapt this to mobile pages.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1100px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.site-nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
  background: #fee17c;
}

.site-nav .nav-logo {
  height: 230px;
}

.site-nav .nav-logo img {
  height: 160px;
  margin: auto;
  background:red;
}

.site-nav .nav-links {
  height: 230px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box {
  height: 230px;
  display: flex;
}

/*@media (min-width: 768px) {*/
  .site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: red;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    padding: 1rem 0 1rem 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding: .7rem 1rem .7rem 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: right;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 1rem;
  }
  .site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box ul li:not(:last-child) {
    padding-right: 1rem;
  }
  .site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box ul li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: .5s;
  }
  .site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box ul li a:hover {
    color: #0864bb;
  }
/*}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 230px;
    left: 0;
    background: 768px-bg;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fee17c;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  }
  .site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box ul li {
    padding: 1rem 0 1rem 1.5rem;
  }
  .site-nav .nav-links .nav-links-box ul.show {
    display: block;
  }
}*/

.site-nav .nav-links .toggle-nav {
  width: 35px;
  height: 230px;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  display: none;
}
/*
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .site-nav .nav-links .toggle-nav {
    display: block;
  }
}
*/
.site-nav .nav-links .toggle-nav .dashes {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.site-nav .nav-links .toggle-nav .dashes .dash {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #0864bb;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: transform .4s, -webkit-transform .4s;
}

.site-nav .nav-links .toggle-nav .dashes .dash:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.site-nav .nav-links .toggle-nav.show .dashes .dash:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(9px) rotate(45deg);
}

.site-nav .nav-links .toggle-nav.show .dashes .dash:nth-child(2) {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.site-nav .nav-links .toggle-nav.show .dashes .dash:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<nav class="site-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-logo">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/230x230" alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- .nav-logo -->
    <div class="nav-links">
      <button class="toggle-nav">
          <span class="dashes" aria-hidden="true">
              <span class="dash"></span>
              <span class="dash"></span>
              <span class="dash"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="txt">Menu</span>
      </button>
      <!-- .toggle-nav -->
      <div class="nav-links-box">
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .nav-links -->
  </div>
  <!-- .container -->
</nav>
<!-- .site-nav -->
```

This way you won't reach the right side of the page with the background tho. That is because your container has a max width and doesn't go that far. There are many ways to go around that, but it's not straightforward. The easiest way might be to remove the max-width from the container, and then give the internal elements margins on the right and left.

Comment: Thank you, this has solved one of my problems. I understand that if I modify it, will it be on mobile? With this second problem, the background right from the container I did not understand? What am I supposed to do to make it work?